# FindFirstFile Issues can't get any example to work.

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, file

I keep having issues with the FindFirstFile and FindNextFile I need to get them to list all dlls into an array but I cant get it to list any files. I have tried using and editing the example code from MSDN but that doesn't work either they pass the wrong type of variable to a function. The code I have now is below sorry if it's a mess but I am trying everything to get it to work. I was also using `argv[1]` because I believe that gives the directory of the `.exe` which is what I need because that were the dlls will be stored. I am completely confused by why all the examples I try don't work and why I can't amend them to work.

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

string directorySearch = "E:\\My Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\SEP-Asignment-One\\Debug\\*";

// Find the first file in the directory.
hFind = FindFirstFile(LPCWSTR("E:\\My Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\SEP-Asignment-One\\Debug\\*"), &FindFileData);

if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
{
  printf ("Invalid file handle. Error is %u.\n", GetLastError());
} 
else
{
  printf ("First file name is %s.\n", FindFileData.cFileName);

                    // List all the other files in the directory.
  while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData) != 0) 
  {
     printf ("Next file name is %s.\n", FindFileData.cFileName);
  }
  FindClose(hFind);
```

Any Help would be apreceated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `std::wstring`, wide string literals like `L"Hello"`, and remember to defined `UNICODE` before including `<windows.h>` (but that's done by default in a Visual Studio project).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of
`hFind = FindFirstFile(LPCWSTR("...")...`,
try 
`hFind = FindFirstFile(_T("...")`

Comment: I don't understand why you think (by recommending `_T`) that it's important to support MFC DLLs for Windows 9x? That's sort of like 14 years ago. Or counting from the introduction of Layer for Unicode in 2000, it's 12 years ago.

Comment: We use code that can be compiled into either Unicode or Multi-Byte Character Set depending on the requirement of the application, so _T("string") is more appropriate than L"string" -- if the code is only for Unicode, L"string" would of course be a better solution...

Comment: Sorry, you're just recapitulating what `_T` does technically, and the "so" concusion is pure balderdash, rubbish, does not follow. The point of `_T`, prior to the year 2000, was to support MFC DLLs in Windows 9x. After the year 2000 there has been no point at all, so why are you recommending it?'

Comment: I'm not very sure what you mean by _T being there to only support Win9x -- there are enough MBCS programs out there, even for Win7, when there is no need for multiple languages, it all depends on what you use for what you need; take a look at the MFC sources (like afxtoolbar.cpp)!

Comment: You're right, `_T` is also there to support old code that supports MFC DLLs in Windows 9x by using pre-year-2000 technology. In a recent informal poll about whether to remove ANSI support in MFC a surprising number of such old code monstrosities turned out to still be maintained. You are mentioning this as if you believe the OP has to support such old code. Lemme tell you, the OP does *not* have to support 15 year old MFC code.